# Code-Challenge: Farey sequence (II)

Tags: math, fastest-code

### Challenge

> In this task you would be given an integer N
>   (less than 10^6), output the number of terms in the [Farey
>   sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) of order N.

The input N < 10<sup>6</sup> is given in a single line, the inputs are terminated by EOF.

The challenge is to implement the fastest solution so that it can process a maximum of 10<sup>6</sup>-1 values as fast as possible.

**Input**

```
7
10
999
9999
79000
123000
```

**Output**

```
19
33
303793
30393487
1897046599
4598679951
```

**Constraints**

- You can use any language of your choice
- Take care about your fingers, do not use more than **4096** bytes of code.
- Fastest solution, based on the running time measured for N = 10<sup>6</sup>-1.

Comment: Are you going to be timing each single submission in the same environment?!

Comment: @J B:I guess the complexity only can do the trick,checking each submission in the same environment will probably give the same result.

Comment: The complexity can be `O(1)` because the input size is limited so we can pre-compute a lookup table...

Comment: @Peter Taylor:Thanks,for pointing that out,I have updated the constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**C - 0.1 Secs on Ideone**

http://www.ideone.com/E3S2t

Explanation included in code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

long long A[1000001]={0};
int main()
{ 
    int isprime[1001],d,n,k,i,e,p; 

    for (n=2;n<1001;n++)
        isprime[n]=1;

    //Sieve of Eratosthenes for Prime
    //Storing the smallest prime which divides n.
    //If A[n]=0 it means it is prime number.
    for(d=2;d<1001;d++)
    {
        if(isprime[d])
        {
            for (n=d*d;n<1001;n+=d)
            {
                isprime[n]=0;
                A[n]=d;
            }
            for (;n<=1000000;n+=d)
                A[n]=d;
        }
    }

    //Uses multiplicative property of
    //Euler Totient Function
    //Phi(n)=Phi(p1^k1)*Phi(p2^k2)...*Phi(pr^kr)
    //and Phi(pi^ki)=(pi-1)*(pi^(ki-1))
    A[1]=1;
    for(n=2;n<=1000000;n++)
    {
        if (A[n]==0)
           A[n]=n-1;
        else
        {
           p=A[n],k=n/p,e=1;
           while (k%p==0)
                 k/=p,e*=p;
           A[n]=A[k]*e*(p-1);
        }
    }
    //Number of terms in Farey Series
    //|F(n)| = 1 + Sigma(i,1,n,phi(i))
    A[1]=2;
    for(n=2;n<=1000000;n++)
        A[n]+=A[n-1];


    while (~scanf("%d",&i))
        printf("%lld\n",A[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

A little more explanation:

> For all numbers we get a prime factor
>   of it from the sieve(or 0 if it is a
>   prime). Next we use the fact that ETF
>   is multiplicative. That is if m and n
>   are coprime then
>   `phi(m*n)=phi(m)*phi(n)`. Here we take
>   out the multiple of prime factor out
>   and hence the left part and the
>   multiple part are co-prime. We already
>   have the ETF for the left part since
>   it is either smaller then current
>   value or equal to 1. We only need to
>   calculate the ETF for the multiple
>   which we calculate using the formula
>   `phi(pi^ki)=(pi-1)*(pi^(ki-1))`.

Comment: Between,you approach is slight faster than mine ... would you like to elaborate the implementation,precisely the ETF computation part,theoretically I understand though.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, individual prime factorization like I did is a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

## C - Less than a second for 999999

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"
#define i64 unsigned long long
#define i32 unsigned int
#define PLIM 1100
#define FLIM 1000000

i32 primes[PLIM];
i64 f[FLIM];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    i64 start=clock();
    i32 primesindex=0;
    f[0]=1;
    f[1]=2;
    i32 a,b,c;
    i32 notprime;
    //Make a list of primes
    for(a=2;a<PLIM;a++){
        notprime=0;
        for(b=0;b<primesindex;b++){
            if(!(a%primes[b])){
                notprime=1;
            }
        }
        if(!notprime){
            primes[primesindex]=a;
            primesindex++;
        }
    }
    i32 count,divided;
    i32 nextjump=4;
    i32 modlimit=2;
    i32 invalue;
    a=2;
    for(c=1;c<argc;c++){
        invalue=atoi(argv[c]);
        if(invalue<FLIM && invalue){
            //For each number from a to invalue find the totient by prime factorization
            for(;a<=invalue;a++){
                count=a;
                divided=a;
                b=0;
                while(primes[b]<=modlimit){
                    if(!(divided%primes[b])){
                        divided/=primes[b];
                        //Adjust the count when a prime factor is found
                        count=(count/primes[b])*(primes[b]-1);
                        //Discard duplicate prime factors
                        while(!(divided%primes[b])){
                            divided/=primes[b];
                        }
                    }
                    b++;
                }
                //Adjust for the remaining prime, if one is there
                if(divided>1){
                    count=(count/divided)*(divided-1);
                }
                //Summarize with the previous totients
                f[a]=f[a-1]+(i64)count;
                //Adjust the limit for prime search if needed
                if(a==nextjump){
                    modlimit++;
                    nextjump=modlimit*modlimit;
                }
            }
            //Output result
            printf("%I64u\n",f[invalue]);
        }
    }
    i64 end=clock();
    //printf("Runtime: %I64u",end-start);
    return 0;
}
```

This takes input from command line.

The computation is a simple sum of totients, it's only done once and only up to the biggest input.

Here is an Ideone version: http://www.ideone.com/jVbc0

Comment: Just for the sake of competition Please elaborate your approach precisely the ETF computation and you may  like to change a bit so that IDEONE testing could be done :-)

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

### C (0.2 sec in Ideone)

I thought of adding my approach too: (this is not as fast as Gaurav's)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define N 1000000
 long long Phi[N+1];

 //Sieve ETF

int main(){
   int i,j;

 for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
    Phi[i]=i;

 for(i=2;i<=N;i++){
    if(Phi[i] == i)
       for(j=i;j<=N;j+=i)
           Phi[j] = (Phi[j]/i)*(i-1);
  }

int t,n;

 Phi[1]=2;
 for(i = 2; i < N; i++)
     Phi[i] += Phi[i-1];


for(;~scanf("%d",&n);)
    printf("%lld\n",Phi[n]);

return 0;
}
```

[TESTING ...](http://www.ideone.com/tlDpX)

Answer (score 2):

### J, 0.2s, short code

It feels weird to write ungolfed J, but it actually *is* the language for the task, for once.

```
input =: ". ;. _2 stdin ''
phi =: 5 & p:
max =: >. / input
acc_totient =: +/ \ phi >: i. max
output =: >: (<: input) { acc_totient
echo output
```

Reads input, constructs accumulated sum of totients up to the max, and reads output from there.

Comment: Wow, for a second I thought that code might actually be readable, but the input line at least doesn't make any sense despite the result being stored in an appropriately named variable. :-P

Comment: @eBusiness: aww, c'mon ;) `stdin ''` reads and returns the entire input.  `;. _2` applies the verb on its left to the argument on its right, split line by line.  The verb on its left `".` converts a string to a J noun, it our case a number.  Would it be more readable to you as `input =: ; do each cutLF stdin ''` ?

Comment: I would,'t say that it's very clear, but using word commands does seem to make it look just a tad bit more familiar.

Comment: FWIW, I find it hugely *less* readable, but that's mostly because it does the same in a more convoluted way (unnecessary boxing and unboxing).  Unfortunately, I couldn't find word commands for such simple actions.

Answer (score 2):

## VB.NET, 0.11 s for 10^6

This is basically a totient computation using prime sieve. The time is measured 10 times and the average is computed.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    Dim M As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
    sw.Start()

    Dim is_prime(M) As Integer
    Dim phi(M) As Integer

    For i = 0 To M
        phi(i) = i
        is_prime(i) = True
    Next

    For i = 2 To M
        If is_prime(i) = True Then
            phi(i) = i - 1
            Dim j As Integer = 2 * i
            Do Until j > M
                is_prime(j) = False
                phi(j) = phi(j) - (phi(j) / i)
                j += i
            Loop
        End If
    Next

    Dim result As Long = 1
    For i = 1 To M
        result += phi(i)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(result)
    sw.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine("Time Elasped : " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    Dim a = Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!